# How to loop the result from findnodes() with HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

Tags: perl, xpath, html-treebuilder

I have my script to monitor some Facebook pages. Since Facebook API banned page public access permission on 4-SEP-2019. I need to parse the content by xpath method.

Each Facebook post is wrap by `div[contains(@class,"userContentWrapper")]`. I would like to loop posts one by one to find a desired data.

I don't known why `$message = $post->findvalue('//div[@data-testid="post_message"]//p');`  show all text in `<p>` of every posts.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua       = new LWP::UserAgent;
$request  = new HTTP::Request;
$request->url('https://www.facebook.com/pg/FIFA/posts/');
$request->method('GET');
$request->header('User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36');
$response = $ua->request($request);


open(HTM, ">zzz.htm");
print HTM $response->content;
close(HTM);


use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
$tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($response->content);


$posts = $tree->findnodes('//div[contains(@class,"userContentWrapper")]');


for my $post (@{$posts})
{
    $id =  $post->findnodes('//div[@data-testid="story-subtitle"]/@id');
    $id =  $id->[0]->getValue;
    print "id = $id\n\n";

    $object_id =  $post->findnodes('//div[@data-testid="story-subtitle"]//a/@href');
    $object_id =  'https://www.facebook.com' . $object_id->[0]->getValue;
    print "object_id = $object_id\n\n";

    $message = $post->findvalue('//div[@data-testid="post_message"]//p');
#   $message = $message->[0]->getValue;
    print "$message\n\n";

    $ajaxify =  $post->findnodes('//div[@class="mtm"]//a/@ajaxify');
    $ajaxify =  $ajaxify->[0]->getValue;
    print "ajaxify = $ajaxify\n\n";

    $ploi = $post->findnodes('//div[@class="mtm"]//a/@data-ploi');
    $ploi = $ploi->[0]->getValue;
    print "ploi = $ploi\n\n";

#   $plsi = $post->findnodes('//div[@class="mtm"]//a/@data-plsi');
#   $plsi = $plsi->[0]->getValue;
#   print "plsi = $plsi\n\n";

    $href =  $post->findnodes('//div[@class="mtm"]//a/@href');
    $href =  'https://www.facebook.com' . $href->[0]->getValue;
    print "href = $href\n\n";

    print "---------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
}
```

Comment: When calling `$post->findnodes` the XPath expression should probably start with a dot, e.g.: `'.//div[@data-testid="story-subtitle"]//a/@href'`.  The dot make it a relative path.  Starting with a slash means it starts at the top of the document.

Comment: Thank, Work now. So `$post->findnodes` still known all data equivalent with `$tree`.

Comment: @ต้อง เอกมัย, A leading `/` means start at the root just like with file paths. `//div[...]/...` is short for `/descendant:div[...]/...`. If you want to start with a child of the context node, simply use `div[...]/...`. If you want to start with a descendant of the current node use `descendant:div[...]/...` or `.//div[...]/...`.

Answer (score 3):

The post is unclear and it seems to contain multiple questions. This needs to be fixed, but in the mean time, I'll address the following:

> *I would like to loop posts one by one to find a desired data.*

---

From [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath),

> **findnodes ($path)**
>
> Returns a list of nodes found by `$path`. In scalar context returns an `Tree::XPathEngine::NodeSet` object.

From [Tree::XPathEngine::NodeSet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tree::XPathEngine::NodeSet),

> **get_nodelist()**
>
> Returns a list of nodes. See [Tree::XPathEngine::XMLParser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tree::XPathEngine::XMLParser) for the format of the nodes.

So,

```
my @posts = $tree->findnodes('...');
for my $post (@posts) { ... }
```

or

```
my $posts = $tree->findnodes('...');
for my $post ($posts->get_nodelist()) { ... }
```

---

Any other questions should be posted as separate Questions.

Comment: I have check `print $post->as_HTML();` is valid. It changed in every loop. But `$id` is the same for every loop. `$message` also weird too.

Comment: I don't understand. Is that a new question?